# Set value of Telegram Dice

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

I'd like to set the value of the dice  before the bot sends the animation of it using
`bot.send_dice(update.message.chat_id, emoji='')`

Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddice) does not provide a way for that. the closest you can get is forwarding a message with the desired value or sending an animated sticker instead.